# FindParent<T> is null while using WPFToolkit:Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When I am using xaml code.

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid1" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MainSearchBinding}"  
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" SelectionMode="Extended"
          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="True"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True" 
          RowHeaderWidth="17" SelectionChanged="DataGrid1_SelectionChanged"
          MouseDoubleClick="OnDoubleClick" MouseLeftButtonUp="OnMouseClick">
```

It is working fine.
While switching to `<WpfToolkit:Datagrid></WpfToolkit:Datagrid>`:

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid Name="DataGrid1" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MainSearchBinding}"  
                     HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" SelectionMode="Extended"
                     CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                     CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="True"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True" 
                     RowHeaderWidth="17" SelectionChanged="DataGrid1_SelectionChanged"
                     MouseDoubleClick="OnDoubleClick" MouseLeftButtonUp="OnMouseClick">
```

I am having error:

> "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: element"

with `FindParent<T>(...)` in this line:

```
DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

public static T FindParent<T>(this DependencyObject child)
        where T : DependencyObject
{
    //get parent item
    DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

    //we've reached the end of the tree
    if (parentObject == null) return null;

    //check if the parent matches the type we're looking for
    var parent = parentObject as T;
    if (parent != null)
    {
        return parent;
    }
    else
    {
        return FindParent<T>(parentObject);
    }
}
```

My code behind is here. It is opening new tab if you click on datagrid cells.

```
var tabControl = (sender as DataGrid).FindParent<TabControl>();
tabControl.Items.Add(new TabItem() { Header = "Документ", Content = docview, IsSelected = true });
```

I know that I am missing something, please show me where to move? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line here:

```
var tabControl = (sender as DataGrid).FindParent<TabControl>();
```

The WPF Toolkit DataGrid has class `Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid`, whereas the built-in WPF DataGrid has class `System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid`.  If your `sender` object is a WPF Toolkit DataGrid, and the `DataGrid` in the line of code above is the built-in WPF DataGrid, then `sender as DataGrid` will be null.  The WPF Toolkit `DataGrid` is completely separate to the built-in `DataGrid` and in particular does not inherit from it.

Fortunately, this problem is easy to fix.  You don't need to cast `sender` to either `DataGrid` class.  Your `FindParent<T>` extension method works on `DependencyObject`s, and both `DataGrid` classes inherit from `DependencyObject`, so you can write

```
var tabControl = (sender as DependencyObject).FindParent<TabControl>();
```

instead.

Comment: Hi Luke, First of all thank you for your time to help me. I tried as you wrote me. it is giving the same error: ArgumentNUllException was handled. Value can not be null, Parameter name:element. Showing this line        DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);    var tabControl = (sender as DependencyObject).FindParent<TabControl>();

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov: I'm a little confused because you've added a comment saying my suggested fix didn't work, but you later accepted my answer.  Did it work or not?

Comment: var tabControl = (sender as Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid).FindParent<TabControl>();  I did this and it worked, Your hint helped me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, your error is going to be coming from the line:

```
DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
```

because `child` will be `null`. You are trying to cast `sender` to a `DataGrid`, which is why it works the first time, since you are using a `DataGrid`. But the second time, I assume you are using a different `DataGrid` (perhaps a custom one); so the cast will return `null`. Therefore, when calling `FindParent(...)`, `child` will be `null`.

When getting the error, have a look at the stack trace and see where the error is originating from. It should show you the exact line and, when looking with a debugger, you should be able to see which value is `null`.

Comment: My question is why it is returning null when I am using custom Datagrid? So this is driving me crazy. Maybe problem is in FindParent<T>. What do you think?

Comment: Which DataGrid are you trying to cast sender to?  If it's System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid then the cast will return null unless WpfToolkit.DataGrid is derived from that class.  But I believe they are separate implementations (WpfToolkit.DataGrid being a precursor of the WPF 4 DataGrid), which means you can't cast between the two.  Why are you trying to cast to DataGrid at all?  Just cast to DependencyObject.

Comment: How to cast DependencyObject? I tried this code, It did not help   var tabControl = (sender as DependencyObject).FindParent<TabControl>(); Please help.

Comment: var tabControl = (sender as Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid).FindParent<TabControl>(); I tried this and it worked thanks for contribution.