# Trying to replace a tail recursive call by a loop

Tags: c#, tail-recursion

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138894/findparentt-is-null-while-using-wpftoolkitdatagrid) question there is a recursive function that finds a parent :

```
public static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
{
    DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    if (parentObject == null) return null;
    var parent = parentObject as T;
    if (parent != null)
    {
        return parent;
    }
    return FindParent<T>(parentObject);
}
```

Resharper offers me to convert it to a loop instead of recursion, it does it like that :

```
public static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
{
    while (true)
    {
        DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
        if (parentObject == null) return null;
        var parent = parentObject as T;
        if (parent != null)
        {
            return parent;
        }
        child = parentObject;
    }
}
```

---

Now I have a function that collapses expanded groups and all its sub-groups :

Unfortunately Reshaper does not offer me to convert it like the one above :(

```
private void MenuItemCollapseAll_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // ... truncated for brievety
    IEnumerable<CollectionViewGroup> groups = grid.Items.Groups.OfType<CollectionViewGroup>().ToArray();
    CollapseGroups(grid, groups);
}

public void CollapseGroups(DataGridControl grid, IEnumerable<CollectionViewGroup> groups)
{
    foreach (var @group in groups)
    {
        grid.CollapseGroup(group);
        var subGroups = @group.Items.OfType<CollectionViewGroup>().ToArray();
        if (subGroups.Any())
        {
            CollapseGroups(grid, subGroups);
        }
    }
}
```

I just can't figure out how to convert it in the same way using a `while` statement, not entirely sure whether it's possible for this very function.

Any ideas ?

Comment: No need for `if (subGroups.Any()) { CollapseGroups(grid, subGroups); }` -- just call CollapseGroups.  If the subGroups array is empty, the method will exit immediately.  If you're so concerned about efficiency that you don't want to call the method needlessly, then you should use `if (subGroups.Length == 0)` instead of using the `Any` extension method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's not tail-recursive.**  After the recursive call comes another iteration of the foreach loop.  But, not all hope is lost.

What you can do to convert it to iteration is make a `Stack<Tuple<DataGridControl, IEnumerable<CollectionViewGroup>>` and replace the recursive call with pushing a new tuple onto the stack.  Then loop until the stack is exhausted.

But first, I notice that the first parameter never changes.  So the iterative version doesn't actually need to keep that on the stack:

```
public void CollapseGroups(DataGridControl grid, IEnumerable<CollectionViewGroup> groups)
{
    var to_process = new Stack<IEnumerable<CollectionViewGroup>>();
    to_process.Push(groups);
    do {
        groups = to_process.Pop();
        foreach (var @group in groups)
        {
            grid.CollapseGroup(@group);
            to_process.Push(@group.Items.OfType<CollectionViewGroup>());
        }
    } while (to_process.Count > 0);
}
```